# About Emoticons in android 2.3.7

Tags: java, android, unicode, emoticons

I'm trying to make a chat app in android, I wanna add emotions in my app.. 
I used unicode in android 4.4.2 and it worked fine..

But when I try to use it in android 2.3.7 it doesn't work.. So how can i use emoticons in android 2.3.7 and in android 2.3.7 there is emoticons panel in Messaging (Insert Smiley) does that use unicode ? And if it uses it how can I get characters unicode ? I googled for it but found nothing.

I want it to be like this in my code :

array.add(new Emoticon(unicode, ":D")): // Emoticon class is a custom class with constructor (String unicode, String Shortcut)

Thanks :)

Comment: The font changed between 2.3.7 and 4.4.2. So, copy the 4.4.2 font into the asset directory of your app and assign that font to your TextView.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement in your app emoticons keyboard you can use in this great library: 
https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon 
This shows a popup window with emojicons over the soft keyboard.
in this library you can find EmojiconHandler class and there you can see this code that generate the emoticons:

```
        sEmojisMap.put(0x1f604, R.drawable.emoji_1f604);
        sEmojisMap.put(0x1f603, R.drawable.emoji_1f603);
        sEmojisMap.put(0x1f600, R.drawable.emoji_1f600);
        sEmojisMap.put(0x1f60a, R.drawable.emoji_1f60a);
        sEmojisMap.put(0x263a, R.drawable.emoji_263a);
        sEmojisMap.put(0x1f609, R.drawable.emoji_1f609);....
```

more of that  , in this site :
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm
you can convert emoticons from UTF-16 to java source code like this example:
UTF-16 --->  0x1f604 in java source code equls to ---> "\uD83D\uDE03"